# Unable to set many characters to the field separator in AWK

Tags: awk

I want to have -[space] as an field separator in AWK.

For instance,

```
awk -F-[space] {' print $1 '}
```

How can you have many characters as a field separator in AWK?

**[edit]**

**The exact output of Vlad's command**

```
$echo /Users/Sam/Dropbox/Education/Chemistry/Other\ materials/*.pdf | sed -e 's: : - :g'
/Users/Sam/Dropbox/Education/Chemistry/Other - materials/CHE_IB_LAB.pdf - /Users/Sam/Dropbox/Education/Chemistry/Other - materials/Lecture19_20_21.pdf
```

**The exact output of Vlad's command with sed**

```
$echo /Users/Sam/Dropbox/Education/Chemistry/Other\ materials/*.pdf
/Users/Sam/Dropbox/Education/Chemistry/Other materials/CHE_IB_LAB.pdf /Users/Sam/Dropbox/Education/Chemistry/Other materials/Lecture19_20_21.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Know your quoting  :) , but be aware that GNU `awk`'s `-F` takes an extended regular expression (ERE) as its argument so you may also need to escape accordingly if you want a textual match as opposed to an ERE match, e.g.

```
awk -F '- ' '{ print $1 }'
```

**UPDATE**

Your latest comment is still unclear.

1. What are the **full** paths of the PDF files on your disk
2. what is the exact output you require from those files?

I need a concrete example, e.g.

1. for the following files:

   ```
   ../Phy/Phy1/file1.pdf
   ../Phy/file2.pdf
   ../Che/Che1/file3.pdf
   ../Che/file4.pdf
   ../file5.pdf
   ../Phy2/file6.pdf
   ```
2. I want to display:

   ```
   PhyPhy1 file1.pdf - Phy file2.pdf - Che/Che1 file3.pdf - Che file4.pdf
   ```

Please note that, in the case of the example files above, the command:

```
echo lpr ../{Che,Phy}/{*.pdf,*/*.pdf}
```

will *only* display:

```
lpr Che/file4.pdf
lpr Che/Che1/file3.pdf
lpr Phy/file2.pdf
lpr Phy/Phy1/file1.pdf
```

Let's get this part right first, then we'll worry about the dash etc.

---

**UPDATE**

OK.  Please run one or both of the following *almost* equivalent commands:

```
echo Dropbox/Mas/edu/{Phy,Che}/*.pdf | sed -e 's: : - :g'
ls -1d Dropbox/Mas/edu/{Phy,Che}/*.pdf | paste -s -d '|' - | sed -e 's:|: - :g'
```

Then please edit your original post and add the following, *separated*:

1. the exact output of the above command(s) (copy-paste)
2. the exact output of the above command(s) *altered* by you to suit your need

Comment: I cannot get the whitespace to work as a field separator. Do you see any mistake in the following code $echo lpr /../{Che,Phy}/{*.pdf,*/*.pdf} | awk -F ' - ' '{ print $1 }' ?

Comment: t prints me just the first occurrence. I would like to print all occurrences. Perhaps, my mistake is in the $1. Does it mean print all occurences?

Comment: print $1 prints the first column... what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: are you perchance trying to insert a dash between the pdf filenames? if so then use sed to replace spaces with e.g. space-dash-space: $echo a b c d | sed -e 's: : - :g'

Comment: @Vlad: I am trying to dipslay pdf filenames as a list, instead of a row, by AWK.

Comment: as what kind of list? comma-separated? one file name per row? provide an accurate example of the desired output please.  e.g. to list one file per row you can do "ls -1 /../{Che,Phy}/{*.pdf,*/*.pdf}" or "for file in /../{Che,Phy}/{*.pdf,*/*.pdf} ; do echo $file ; done"

Comment: The items in the list are separated by the mark -. An example is PhyPhy1 FilePath1 - Phy2 Filepath2 - CheChe1 filepath1 - Che2 filepath

Comment: 1. the full path is Dropbox/Mas/edu/{Phy,Che}/*.pdf
2. The output needs to be in the list form. It looks now like Path1 - Path2 - Path3 - Pathn

Comment: What does the following mean sed -e 's: : - :g'? My attempt: You try to append...

Comment: sed -e 's: : - :g' will replace all occurrences of " " with " - ".  Now, just what I was afraid of: your path has spaces in it, so you must use the SECOND command (with 'ls -1d'.)  Thank you for adding the commands' output, but you have not said whether it's OK as it is or, if not, what must change.

Comment: in sed's 's: : - :g', s is for substitute, g is for global. You could have also written this as 's/ / - /g' or 's# # - #g' or 's| | - |g' - you get the hang of it.  See 'man sed' or  http://unix.compufutura.com/sedawk/ch02_03.htm for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: @Vlad: The new ls command does not work, but the previous one work nearly as I want. I have tried to put enters for the sed command unsuccessfully by 's/ /\n/g'. It seems that sed does not support carriage return: the same problem here http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1065610&page=1

Comment: @Masi, when you say that ls does not work, what is the exact error or output?  Also, "echo ..." will output everything on one line, and there is no way to distinguish between the spaces naturally occurring inside the filenames, and spaces separating different file names

Comment: "ls -1d" does what echo cannot do, i.e. output one filename per line (with \n"), and "paste" will glue all lines together separated by the single character passed to -d (e.g. |) which can then be sed'ed away to a multi-character separator

Comment: If "paste" is the problem on your system then you can also do:        ls -1d Dropbox/Mas/edu/{Phy,Che}/*.pdf | tr '\n' '|' | sed -e 's:|*$::' -e 's: : - :g'

Comment: tr will replace all "\n" characters with '|', almost like paste, except that the last "\n" (after the last file) will also be replaced and has to be trimmed with 's:|*$::' (all | at the end of a line replaced with blanks), which was not an issue with "paste"